# How to allow downloading multiple files again in Chrome?

Tags: chrome-for-android, downloading

When I was recently downloading files from a website, Chrome warned me, that website tries to download multiple files. I haven't seen that warning before and I guessed, that this may be security feature to prevent downloading unwanted .apk files, so I answered "no" (I disallow). Now I can download only one file at a time from that website and I have to reload whole page before downloading another. Really annoying.

Is there a way to undo my decision and allow downloading multiple files again? Or maybe disable this "feature" altogether?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type in address bar `chrome://flags` and search for *parallel*. Change options for *parallel downloading* (Default / enabled / disabled)

Not tested but flags change the behavior and this is most likely what you want

Comment: You can ignore the warning in red on opening the flags page. You aren't doing anything dangerous

Answer (score 1):

When this happened to me I clicked Google chrome Settings & under Advanced I chose Site Settings > Automatic Downloads then deleted the website link that was previously not allowed to perform multiple downloads under the "not allowed or block" section and copied the website link to the "allowed" section. If you don't want to be asked each time you're trying to download something turn off the "Ask first' button under Automatic Downloads sections.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by going into "Settings > Privacy > Clear browsing data". Under the "Advanced" tab select "Cookies and site data" and "Site settings". Tap on "Clear Data".

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this answer while trying to solve this on Brave desktop browser.
This is how I resolved it.

1. URL: [brave://settings/content/all](https://brave://settings/content/all)
2. Find the website you were on when you denied multiple downloads.
3. Click the trash can
4. Reload the site and click the download again.

Navigation:

- Select "Settings" from the top right Hamburger button (three
  horizontal lines)
- Select "Privacy and security"
- Select "Cookies and other site data"
- Select "See all site data and permissions"

*Version 1.46.133 Chromium: 108.0.5359.71 (Official Build) (64-bit)*